# Ruby on Rails - Partial with random variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

I render a partial in my view like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_shipping_address').click(function(e){
    $('#shipping_addresses').append("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'shipping_address' ) %>");
  });
});
</script>
```

The partial renders fine but in my partial I got a random variable

```
<% random_id = rand(9999999) %>
```

The strange thing is every time I render the partial via click on that button the random variable is the same, like it gets generated once and then just gets repeated. Is that a normal behaviour and if so, what can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The content for the partial is rendered once on the server side and then inserted into the DOM X times on the client-side, this is why the random value is always the same.  You can either:

1. Generate the random value using JS (see [Generating random whole numbers in JavaScript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range))
2. Call a server-side action to render and insert another partial
3. Make some sort of server-side JSON API that produces random values

NOTE (not the root cause of the above issue, but worth mentioning): If you are using some kind of cache (like [varnish](https://www.varnish-cache.org/)), partial content can remain unchanged even on new requests, In this case, you could move the generation of the random number to the controller.

Comment: if its a caching problem you could also use a cache buster .. e.G a random part in the url

Comment: It's not a cache problem. Can I pass the random variable generated via JS as a local in my render call?

Comment: Why can't you create the random number on the controller and pass it to the view?

Comment: @StephanS. the render call only happens once on the server-side.  If you look at the source of that page after it has loaded the full contents of the partial will be in the `append` function and not the actual render call anymore.